El ResultSet no contiiene ninguna fila
Estoy haciendo una consulta desde java, pero al momento de ejecutar el metódo, me arroja que el ResultSet no contine ninguna fila.
Este es el código que hice:
public ArrayList<ePermisos> getAll(ePermisos permisos)
{
    ArrayList<ePermisos> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    
    try
    {
        CallableStatement cs = conn.getConnection().prepareCall("{Call stp_Permisos_getByUser (?)}");
        
        cs.setInt(1, permisos.getId());
        
        ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
        
        while(rs.next())
        {
            ePermisos permiso = new ePermisos();
            permiso.setMenu(rs.getString("Menu"));
            permiso.setOpcion1(rs.getBoolean("Opcion1"));
            permiso.setOpcion2(rs.getBoolean("Opcion2"));
            permiso.setOpcion3(rs.getBoolean("Opcion3"));
            permiso.setOpcion4(rs.getBoolean("Opcion4"));
            permiso.setOpcion5(rs.getBoolean("Opcion5"));
            permiso.setOpcion6(rs.getBoolean("Opcion6"));
            lista.add(permiso);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                                      "Error al obtener la lista de permisos del usuario.\n" + ex.getMessage(), 
                                      "TOP-SUELAS", 
                                      JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                                      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.closeConnection();
    }
    
    return lista;
}

Debo aclarar que no me arroja ningún mensaje de error, el error lo descubri porque antes de la instrucción while, puse la siguiente linea:
System.out.println(rs.getString("Menu"));

Ya cheque que el valor si llega a esta instancia, y tambien cheque que el procedimiento almacenado hiciera bien la consulta.

Podrías agregar tu objeto ePermisos ?

Para que ver el objeto ePermisos, solo es una clase que contiene los set y get, pero el problema es que cuando llega a la instrucción while, pasa directamente al finally, como si ya hubiera checho la consulta

Si no marca error y comentas que cuando llega a la instrucción while, entonces el problema es simplemente que el valor de permisos.getId() es un valor que no obtiene resultados, debes revisar que obtiene en este valor.
CallableStatement cs = conn.getConnection().prepareCall("{Call stp_Permisos_getByUser (?)}");
        
cs.setInt(1, permisos.getId())


permisos.getId() esta variable, contiene un id de un usuario, como ya dije arriba, el valor si llega desde mi capa de vistas, pero al momento de ejecutar la consulta, no me devuelve los datos

Ya lo resolvi, estaba mandando la variable equivocada, por eso el procedimiento no me mandaba nada

@Macx cual variable era equivocada? Si te refieres a permisos.getId(), es precisamente lo que comento en mi respuesta.

El valor lo capturo en la variable permisos.getUsuario(), pero yo mandaba permisos.getId(), que no tiene ningun valor, y por lo tanto la consulta no regresaba nada
